# Python byte decode for JPEG EXIF data fails

Tags: python, jpeg, decode

I am trying to decode JPEG EXIF data using Pillow. When I decode, I either get a parsing error or the decode results in hex instead of actually decoding the bytes.

Here is my code based on work by Abdou Rockikz https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/extracting-image-metadata-in-python

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL.ExifTags import TAGS
# path to the image or video
imagename = "image.jpg"

# read the image data using PIL
image = Image.open(imagename)

# extract EXIF data
exifdata = image.getexif()

# iterating over all EXIF data fields
for tag_id in exifdata:
    # get the tag name, instead of human unreadable tag id
    tag = TAGS.get(tag_id, tag_id)
    data = exifdata.get(tag_id)
    # decode bytes 
    if isinstance(data, bytes):
        data = data.decode()
    print(f"{tag:25}: {data}")
```

I have tried `.decode('utf-8')` (the default), which results in the following error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xea in position 1: invalid continuation byte`.

I have tried `latin-1` and `ISO-8859-1` but these result in a huge hex output rather than human readable values such as `\x00\x08...`. The values are fine when I decode TIF images but JPEGs don't seem to work for some reason. Is there a decoding scheme I need to be aware of or some other process? Thanks!

Comment: Are you having the same problem with all .jpg files, or just  a particular file?    And exactly which line is throwing the error?  You could try putting the last three lines inside a Try/Except block to see if its only certain data elements throwing the exception or if all the data is bad.